# Run INSERT statement with concatenated date to table name

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-insert

Is it possible to run a query where you concat the date into the table to get the required table?

Such as:

```
INSERT INTO schema.table_ || replace(cast(now()::date  AS varchar), '-', '_') ||
(row,id,value,date) VALUES
...;
```

where table name I'm trying to access is table_2020_12_14?

Comment: Not without something else generating the SQL. You may wish to consider turning them into [table partitions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-partitioning.html).

Comment: I'm trying to access a partition table.

Comment: You should not need to insert into a specific table. Insert into the master table and it will go into the appropriate partition.

Comment: @user300 . . . This indicates a problem with the data model.  You should be putting all the data into a *single table* with the date as a column (perhaps used for partitioning).

Comment: So, to make sure I'm understanding correctly, as long as the parent table is created with some chosen column to partition by, If I insert data into the parent table, it will automatically create the partitioned tables?

Answer (score 0):

No, that is not possible. You have to first generate the statement as a string, then execute it. One way to do that is dynamic SQL in PL/pgSQL with `EXECUTE`.

If that is a table partition, then the exercise is unnecessary, and you can directly insert into the partitioned table.